# Unable to write the SQL query as per my required output

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have two tables in MS Access database (Table1, Table2) with same columns namely `Id`, `PartNo`, `Nomenclature`, `Quantity` and `Wksp`. Id is the primary key in them. Id can be same in both tables. Now I want to write a query to get the output as shown under required output. How can I achieve this?

```
Table1
+----+--------+--------------+----------+----------+
| Id | PartNo | Nomenclature | Quantity |   Wksp   |
+----+--------+--------------+----------+----------+
|  1 | Part1  | Nomenc1      |        2 |    Wksp1 |
|  2 | Part2  | Nomenc2      |        4 |    Wksp1 |
|  3 | Part3  | Nomenc3      |        6 |    Wksp1 |
|  4 | Part4  | Nomenc4      |        8 |    Wksp1 |
+----+--------+--------------+----------+----------+

Table2
+----+--------+--------------+----------+-------+
| Id | PartNo | Nomenclature | Quantity | Wksp  |
+----+--------+--------------+----------+-------+
|  1 | Part1  | Nomenc1      |        1 | Wksp2 |
|  2 | Part2  | Nomenc2      |        3 | Wksp2 |
|  3 | Part3  | Nomenc3      |        5 | Wksp2 |
|  4 | Part11 | Nomenc11     |        7 | Wksp2 |
|  5 | Part7  | Nomenc7      |        9 | Wksp2 |
+----+--------+--------------+----------+-------+
```

Required Output

```
+----+--------+--------------+-------+-------+
| Id | PartNo | Nomenclature | Wksp1 | Wksp2 |
+----+--------+--------------+-------+-------+
|  1 | Part1  | Nomenc1      |     2 |     1 |
|  2 | Part2  | Nomenc2      |     4 |     3 |
|  3 | Part3  | Nomenc3      |     6 |     5 |
|  4 | Part11 | Nomenc11     |     0 |     7 |
|  5 | Part7  | Nomenc7      |     0 |     9 |
|  6 | Part4  | Nomenc4      |     8 |     0 |
+----+--------+--------------+-------+-------+
```

[image: Tables and required Output Image]

Comment: You need a full outer join, which will probably be messy in Access.

Comment: So the IDs in the original tables are irrelevant for the result? -- Is the new ID in the output actually required?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First create a query to collect the IDs:

```
SELECT Id
FROM Table1
UNION 
SELECT Id
FROM Tabel2;
```

Save this as, say, *TBboth*.

Then use this as source:

```
SELECT 
    TBboth.Id, 
    Nz(Table1!PartNo, Table2!PartNo) AS PartNo, 
    Nz(Table1!Nomenclature, Table2!Nomenclature) As Nomenclature, 
    Sum(Nz(Table1!Quantity,0)) AS Wksp1, 
    Sum(Nz(Table2!Quantity,0)) AS Wksp2
FROM 
    (TBboth 
    LEFT JOIN 
        TB1 ON TBboth.Id = TB1.Id) 
    LEFT JOIN 
        TB2 ON TBboth.Id = TB2.Id
GROUP BY 
    TBboth.Id, 
    Nz(Table1!PartNo, Table2!PartNo), 
    Nz(Table1!Nomenclature, Table2!Nomenclature);
```

Comment: Thanks a ton Sir it worked but have an issue with the output. it concatenates the values twice under columns PartNo, Nomenclature as P1P1, N1N1 ideally it should show only P1 or N1

Comment: You are right. Try the edited answer where _Nz_ is applied for those two fields.

Comment: Sir I have tried with the Nz option I am getting the same output

Comment: I got the desired output Sir had forgot to replace & with ‘,’ thank you Sir

Comment: OK. That explains.

Comment: Sir, correction required in the query it doesn’t show part11,Part7, Part4 where one of the wksp in case of those part No doesn’t have any value.

Comment: Sir PartNo are unique in each table and it should be grouped as per PartNo and then find the quantity of stock of a particular PartNo in both the wksp in our case we have included group by TBboth.Id

Comment: Made the necessary amendments now all is OK thank you Sir

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select Id , PartNo , Nomenclature, ISNULL(Wksp1,0) Wksp1, ISNULL(Wksp2,0) Wksp2
from 
(
 select  Id , PartNo , Nomenclature ,Wksp,  sum(Quantity) 'count' from Table1
 group by Id , PartNo , Nomenclature,Wksp
 union all
 select  Id , PartNo , Nomenclature ,Wksp,  sum(Quantity) 'count' from Table2
group by Id , PartNo , Nomenclature,Wksp
) src
pivot
(
  sum(count)
  for Wksp in ([Wksp1], [Wksp2])
) P;
```

Comment: But this Access, not T-SQL.

Answer (score -1):

Try with This Method if you are using **MS SQL Server**

```
DECLARE @T1 TABLE
(
    Id INT,
    Part VARCHAR(20),
    Qty INT,
    Wksp VARCHAR(20) DEFAULT('Wksp 1')
)

DECLARE @T2 TABLE
(
    Id INT,
    Part VARCHAR(20),
    Qty INT,
    Wksp VARCHAR(20) DEFAULT('Wksp 2')
)


INSERT INTO @T1
VALUES(1,'Part1',10,'Wksp 1'),(2,'Part2',15,'Wksp 1'),(3,'Part3',12,'Wksp 1')


INSERT INTO @T1
VALUES(1,'Part1',10,'Wksp 2'),(2,'Part2',15,'Wksp 2'),(4,'Part4',20,'Wksp 2')

SELECT
    Id = coalesce(a.id,b.id),
    Part = coalesce(a.Part,b.Part),
    Qty = coalesce(a.Qty,b.Qty),
    Wksp =coalesce(a.Wksp,b.Wksp)
    FROM @T1 A
       FULL JOIN @T2 b
          on a.Id = b.Id
```

Comment: But this Access, not T-SQL.

Comment: @Gustav He had SQL Server Tagged in the Question along with My SQL and Access, that's why I specifically added this is for SQL Server in my answer

Comment: Oh, it has been removed, I can see. The downvoter isn't me.